# bash and expect - doesn't take port while rsyncing

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, rsync

I have a simple script as follows which uses `expect` to rsync some data (over ssh). The code is as follows:

```
local_path1="/root/accordingtojim.txt"
username="ih4d35"
ip="10.0.0.152"
port="22"
password="t3tr@h3dr0n"

echo "$local_path1 $username $ip $port $password"

expect -c 'spawn rsync -avz -e "ssh -p $port" $local_path1 $username\@$ip:~/; expect '*?assword:*' {send \"$password\r\"; interact};'
```

This is the error I get:

```
can't read "port": no such variable
    while executing
"spawn rsync -avz -e "ssh -p $port" $local_path1 $username\@$ip:~/"
```

The `echo` statement works fine though.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell variables aren't expanded between single quotes, so get rid of them and replace the nested quotes with escaped ones:

```
expect -c "spawn rsync -avz -e \"ssh -p $port\" $local_path1 $username\@$ip:~/; expect '*?assword:*' {send \"$password\r\"; interact};"
```